# get all values of a specific key in an array of dictionaries - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filtering

I have this json data below:

```
[{
    "name": "Dad",
    "age": "32"
}, {
    "name": "Mom",
    "age": "30"
}, {
    "name": "Son",
    "age": "3"
}]
```

I would like to have an array: `["Dad", "Mom", "Son"]`.

What is the correct way to implement this in Javascript?

Comment: That is json man, Not dictionary. dictionaries are available in python.

Comment: @Maskedy edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```js
var result=   [{
            "name": "Dad",
            "age": "32"
        }, {
            "name": "Mom",
            "age": "30"
        }, {
            "name": "Son",
            "age": "3"
        }].map( item => { return item.name }); //["Dad", "Mom", "Son"]
        
        console.log(result);

var result=   [{
            "name": "Dad",
            "age": "32"
        }, {
            "name": "Mom",
            "age": "30"
        }, {
            "name": "Son",
            "age": "3"
        }].map( function(item) { return item.name }); //["Dad", "Mom", "Son"]
        
        console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you, how do I implement this without an arrow function?

Comment: Please vote to close obvious duplicates

Comment: @Yosi there you go you have both with and without arrow function